# Cordova Build ios

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, provisioning-profile, cordova-ios

Im trying to peacefully compile a cordova project, and its throwing an error of

`error: No profile for team '[TEAM_ID]' matching 'APP Development' found: Xcode couldn't find any provisioning profiles matching '[TEAM_ID]/APP Development'. Install the profile (by dragging and dropping it onto Xcode's dock item) or select a different one in the Signing & Capabilities tab of the target editor. (in target 'APP' from project 'APP')`

Ive done everything from cleaning the build to everything. When i run the app on Xcode it runs smooth and it builds perfectly! Also was able to deploy to TestFlight perfectly. This issue only occurs when i run it through Terminal `sudo cordova build ios`

Where do i "drag and drop" file?

If anyone has solved this issue please help me. Im running Cordova ios 5.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode saying you need to set

1. Team
2. Provisioning profile.

   - open Xcode
   - click on your a project
   - select targets click on your project
   - select(Siging&Capabilities)on topbar
   - In Sigigng part you need to select team and p.profile.